# Python pygame animation directional loop not working

Tags: python, loops, animation, pygame

So I am going through the pygame book. I'm very new to Python I've read a book and went part way through the coursera course, and also navigated various websites.

My question is; how do I make this image continue to, for example, "zig-zag" down the page?

Down, right, down, right, down, right - until it reaches the bottom of the page then go up to the top and stop?

The issue I am having with the code is that after it goes; down, right, down - it just continues to go down and ignores the code which I wrote.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((1400,1100), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('mchammy')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
pigImg = pygame.image.load('mcsuperpig.png')
pigx = 10
pigy = 10
direction = 'down'

while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)

    if direction == 'down':
        pigy += 2
        if pigy == 100:
            direction = 'right'
    elif direction == 'right':
        pigx += 2
        if pigx == 100:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        pigy += 2
        if pigy == 200:
            direction = 'right'
    elif direction == 'right':
        pigx += 2
        if pigx == 200:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        pigy += 2
        if pigy += 700:
            direction = 'right'

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pig.Img, (pigx, pigy))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically - you are misunderstanding the `while` loop.

Your conditional if/elif clauses are almost useless, each time the `while` loop iterates, it will only enter one of them.. and both options `"down"` and `"right"` are already covered with the first two clauses, meaning you will *never* get to the other ones.

If you change it to:

```
if direction == 'down':
    pigy += 2
    if not pigy % 100:
        direction = 'right'
else:
    pigx += 2
    if not pigx % 100:
        direction = 'down'
```

Then your image will switch directions every 100 pixels it moves in any direction.

---

I recommend you learn more about Python, create a class for your image and some proper functions for the movement. Make your code look nicer, and cleaner - like other code I am sure you have seen throughout your learning Python.

Comment: I tried entering my code into this, but it keeps giving me an indentation error. Could you provide me with an example of making a class for the image? I'm pretty noob. Thank you for your help though! the if not is useful!

Answer (score 1):

As posted, the problem is with your if statement, which is never reaching the bottom three clauses since you have already covered them in the first two

Try this instead:

```
if direction == 'down'
    pigy += 2
    if (pigy == 100) or (pigy == 200) or (pigy == 700)
        direction = 'right'
elif direction == 'right'
    pigx += 2
    if (pigx == 100) or (pigx == 200)
        direction = 'down'
```

you have `if pigy += 700`, which is not valid (since pigy += 700 means increment by 700) so i assume you mean `if pigy == 700`

Hope this puts you on the right track!